# button sound stops after while

Tags: android, audio, soundpool

i have created an app with many sound buttons and problem is that after a while they stop working and i have to reset the app. Is there any way to manage it?

```
public class TwoFragment extends Fragment{

SoundPool mySound1;
int ayyId;
SoundPool mySound2;
int eyyId;
SoundPool mySound3;
int keId;
SoundPool mySound4;
int kraId;
SoundPool mySound5;
int pandaId;
SoundPool mySound6;
int timeId;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mySound1 = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    ayyId = mySound1.load(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.raw.ayy, 1);
    mySound2 = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    eyyId = mySound2.load(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.raw.eyy, 1);
    mySound3 = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    keId = mySound3.load(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.raw.kee, 1);
    mySound4 = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    kraId = mySound4.load(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.raw.kraaa, 1);
    mySound5 = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    pandaId = mySound5.load(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.raw.pandaa, 1);
    mySound6 = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    timeId = mySound6.load(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.raw.time, 1);
        }
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two,container,false);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two,container,false);
    Button des1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.des1);
    Button des2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.des2);
    Button des3 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.des3);
    Button des4 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.des4);
    Button des5 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.des5);
    Button des6 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.des6);
    des1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {mySound1.play(ayyId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);}
    });
    des2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {mySound2.play(eyyId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);}
    });
    des3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {mySound3.play(keId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);}
    });
    des4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {mySound4.play(kraId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);}
    });
    des5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {mySound5.play(pandaId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);}
    });
    des6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {mySound6.play(timeId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);}
    });

    MobileAds.initialize(getActivity(), "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx");
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    return view;

}
}
```

also I wanna ask how to stop button from playing when I click another one. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [.release()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#release). According to docs:

> Release the SoundPool resources. Release all memory and native resources used by the SoundPool object. The SoundPool can no longer be used and the reference should be set to null.

Also you can keep the playing streamid in arraylist, then clear and play when play button is clicked.

```
    List<Integer> streams = new ArrayList<Integer>();
SoundPool pool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

public void onClick(View view) {
    int streamId = 0;
    stop_clear_stream();
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            streamId = pool.play(soundid1, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1, 0, 1.0f);
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            streamId = pool.play(soundid2, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1, 0, 1.0f);
            break;
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .

        streams.add(streamId);

    }
}

private void stop_clear_stream() {
    if (streams != null && streams.size() > 0)
        for (Integer stream : streams)
            pool.stop(stream);

    streams.clear();
}
```

I have not tested the above code though.